# React Updating state bottom up from deeply nested children in a form builder

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, state, persistent-storage

I need help wrapping my head around the best approach to updating a parent state from deeply nested children/grandchildren.

I'm creating a form builder using React that allows users to create, preview, and export forms by saving persistent state in localeStorage. A form has questions and each question has a possible sub-questions.

My thinking is keeping a state of all questions on the app layer, assigning localStorage.setItem('questions', this.state.questions)

The data structure is as follow:

```
     [
      { question='question 1', 
        type='text', 
        condition=null, 
        isSub= false, 
        subQ=[{
            question='sub question 1',
            ...
            isSub=true,
            subQ=[]
          }]
        },
        {
          question='question 1', 
          ...
          isSub= false, 
          subQ=[]
        },
        question='question 1', 
        ...
        isSub= false, 
        subQ=[]
      }
    ]
```

My Component hierarchical structure is App -> QuestionForm -> Question.
App keeps a state of all questions, Question manages its own onChange calling updateInputValue which updates the value then calls updateParent(key, update) which is bound to the QuestionForm component. QuestionForm then calls updateQuestions(update) which is bound to App. This works fine for the outermost layer of questions. What is the best approach for updating the App state with the changes made to sub-questions?

```
   class Question extends Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          question: props.question
        }
        this.updateInputValue = this.updateInputValue.bind(this)
      }
      .....
      updateInputValue(e){
        let { name, value } = e.target, 
            question = {...this.props.question }
        if( !name ){
          value = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('name') || 
                  e.target.getAttribute('name')
          name = 'type'
        } 
        question[name] = value
        this.setState({question: question})
        this.props.updateParent(this.props.id, question)
      }
```

This is how I'm rendering each question's sub-questions inside the Question 
render() component

```
{ question.subQ.map( (q, i) => 
                  <Question key={i} 
                           question={q} 
                        updateParent={this.props.updateParent} /> ) }
```

The updateParent function inside QuestionForm component

```
      updateParent = (key, prop) => {
        let questions = {...this.state.questions }
        questions[key] = prop
        this.props.updateQuestions(questions)
      }
```

Lastly, the App component

```
          class App extends Component {
        constructor(props){
          super(props)
          this.state = {
            questions: sample,
            activeItem: 'Create'
          }
          this.checkStorage = checkStorage
          this.addQuestion = addQuestion.bind(this)
          this.handleTabClick = this.handleTabClick.bind(this)
          this.updateQuestions = this.updateQuestions.bind(this)
        }

        updateQuestions(update){
          this.setState({questions: update})
        }
```

I was thinking a bottom-up approach by keeping track of parentKeys and climbing up the tree until 'isSub' === false. Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Well another approach is to just have a flag bag of state that you pass to every component using redux or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If App is going to store your questions' state, the easiest thing in my opinion would be to just give App an updateQuestion method like this:

```
updateQuestion(path, value) {
  const { questions } = this.state;
  _.set(questions, path, value);
  this.setState({ questions });
}
```

Here, we're using [lodash's `set` method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#set) to transverse the data structure and alter whatever value you need. Now, we can bind this function and pass it down as a prop to each question, and each sub-question as needed.

Then, inside your render method, when you're mapping each Question to your data array, dynamically assign it a `path` prop that reflects the location of the value you'll be changing within your state when that particular Question calls updateQuestion.

Pass down the App's state.questions (or a slice of it) to each Question as prop, and you can avoid having them maintain their own state, meaning unless you need lifecycle hooks, you can just turn Question into a functional component.

Honestly, though, when you find yourself having to bubble up state like this, it's time to ask yourself if redux is not the way to go. You'll have some initial growing mains if you've not used it before, but it will save you a lot of effort and unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't used redux before and time is an issue.

Comment: Since I have to store the data in a persistent state in localStorage, I was wondering if there's a way to take Reacts one-way data flow principle and have each Question component's instance run in parallel with it's reference to localStorage and update the persistentData dynamically based on the current state of the Question component.

Comment: @nzoLogic I imagine you would just include `localStorage.set('questions', questions)` after the call to `setState` in the example function above

Comment: Works! Thank you so much, man. That was giving me a bit of a headache. Cheers!

Comment: @nzoLogic Awesome! Good luck with your endeavor. Please upvote too if you found the answer helpful :)

Comment: I did! Don't have enough rep to influence it yet. I tried using unset to remove but it returns undefined causing my components to crash. What's the best practice for doing the opposite of your answer?

Comment: [These](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) are the methods available to use with localStorage. There's really only setItem and removeItem.

Comment: I'm manipulating a copy of the state after an update or delete function was triggered then stringifying the updated state as the new questions value so I need something to manipulate the array/nested objects directly without returning null. Otherwise my components break

Comment: It's kind of hard to help you debug your code without seeing all of it. If you want to throw up a gist or repo link, I can take a look on there and try to help you that way

Comment: It's in reference to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45042019/lodash-pullat-returning-undefined-at-path/45042261?noredirect=1#comment77059300_45042261)

Comment: Ok, I think I get what you're asking. So, you should be able to use [_.omit()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit) for that. You pass it an object and a path, and it returns the whole object, except for the part at the path. Since we're passing the path of the question to the <Question /> component, if we were to invoke omit on the questions state using that same path, it should delete that particular question.

Comment: That works but it returns a collection of objects. I'm manipulating an array of questions. _.unset does what I need it to, but it returns an 'undefined' value at the location of removal.

Comment: followed by questions =  _toArray(questions)