# lodash _.pullAt returning undefined at path

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, lodash

I'm using lodash in a react app to update and delete nested elements in an array that contains objects which subsequently update my component state and saves to localStorage.

```
 questions = [{"question":"","type":"text","conditions":null,"isSub":false,"subQ":[]}]
 path = '[0]'

    //returns [undefined x 1]
function deleteQuestion(path){  
   const { questions } = this.state
   _.pullAt(questions, path)
  this.setState({questions: questions})
}
```

I'm new to lodash but what's the best way to delete elements by a path without returning null or undefined?

Answer (score 0):

`_.pullAt` takes integers, not a string

```
_.pullAt(questions, 0)  
console.log(questions)  // output is []
```

Comment: What if I'm deleting a child that's in questions[0].subQ[0]? How would I do that? 

I have a form builder in React and attached each child with a path property that corresponds to its location in questions. That's how I'm updating the input using ._set.

Comment: Replace `questions` with your array, in this case `questions[0].subQ`